# Access Facebook Album

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am creating one site in which User will login trough his(er) Facebook a/c.
i algo give functnality that user can access there facebook album in my site so they can access there pic in my site.
can anyone help me on this topic??

Comment: this link for ios but may be helped.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 0):

For that you have  to use facebook's Graph API.

```
public const string AUTHORIZE = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize";
public const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
```

using this you can authorize a user and facebook will return a Access Token using that you can call

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" +
          facebookClientId + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:1388/FBCoverpage/FBcallback.aspx&scope=user_photos";
```

this api and you have to set your redirect uri to g et response on that page. and also have to set client Id which is you application Id that you created on Facebook

THank you.